# Why are downvoted answers muted?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, design, user-interface

In my not so humble opinion graying out posts is a design flaw. On other forums, like reddit and youtube, it's done for the purpose of "defeating spam", but in reality the only purpose it serves is to censor opinions. Posts with less visibility are unlikely to be upvoted and are harder to read because of the muted color. I haven't seen any way to unmute it either other than manually removing the "downvoted-answer" class.

If it's for the purposes of spam, I read somewhere on here asking "why are spam posts not hidden?" The reasoning in the answer was that spam posts are handled so quickly that there's no point in hiding them. On top of that, there's already a built-in mechanism for dealing with spam, which is flagging posts.

So then it must be for the other reason, a soft censorship of posts. What is the reasoning behind this? The downvotes are supposed to be an indication of the post's usefulness or technical accuracy. Even if the answer is highly downvoted, if it hasn't been deleted yet, then it clearly has some value (i.e., serving as a signpost for what not to do.) Muting a post only causes people to either skip over it, or make it harder to work with the post in order to correct it if need be. Once a post has been muted, there's basically no reason to keep it alive except to delete it.

What's the point of this premature death sentence?

Comment: Note that the downvotes here are likely just disagreeing with your opinion.

Comment: Downvoted answers at -3 or worse are grayed out because they're ***bad*** answers.  You'd be surprised how many people hesitate to downvote an answer because they'll take a -1 ding to their reputation, so for an answer to hit -3, the answer needs to be vastly improved, or removed entirely.  If an answer is heavily downvoted, but not deleted, that's because it takes 3 20K+ members to delete it; they may not be immediately available, or have seen the answer.

Comment: To me, that third paragraph just reads as a positive advertisement for greying out bad answers.

Comment: Random thought: should heavily downvoted questions be grayed-out too?

Comment: Humph, after rereading this one.. I actually agree - but only on Meta. I really dislike that we grey out an *opinion* - that right there is Reddit behavior(if my opinion upsets hivemind, oops disappear ). But if your code is wrong, you are grey

Comment: Two things: Stack Exchange is ***not*** a forum and opinion based questions are generally **off topic**

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of the voting system is that good content bubbles up, and poor content is pushed down. The further down it goes, the more it is pushed and that is where the "greying out" (opacity .5) comes from.

If the answer is negatively voted and egregious more often than not it is going to be removed anyway because so many times it is either "Hey, this happened to me too!", or "visit this link", or copy+paste, etc. These answers will show up for higher reputation users in the low quality review queue and be handled accordingly.

If the answer is simply incorrect, or worse dangerous, then the downvotes are deserved and the transparency is just another way to show that the answer is not going to be a valid solution to the problem.

Users want valid solutions, and often they want them quickly (I know I don't like wasting time on invalid solutions). This means that showing the solution which has the best chance at being the valid solution to the current issue should take priority over other solutions.

While this priority design is setup to both save time and increase content quality from a user's perspective, I do not believe that it is censorship (soft or otherwise). The post may still remain if downvoted past -2 as long as it does answer the question (even if it is technically incorrect).

It is merely not placed on a pedestal because it doesn't deserve to be there by community consensus.

Comment: But what about the distinction between Meta and Stackoverflow ? May we not benefit from OP's idea here on Meta

Comment: @Coffee - This answer does take into consideration StackOverflow more than meta, but I believe the point about consensus still stands. It would be a different discussion if the OP made it more clear which avenue they were addressing in their question.