# Official Documentation for fading out questions that have been downvoted?

Tags: bug, questions

Sometimes I notice answers are faded and only become "clear" when I move my cursor over them. For example the last answer on this page:

[Why doesn't getchar() wait for me to press enter after scanf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391548/why-doesnt-getchar-wait-for-me-to-press-enter)

I have been able to replicate this behavior on several computers.

Why does it do that?

NOTE--I had to add bug as a tag because the site wouldn't let me post the question without it.

While another question ([Why are downvoted answers muted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288620/why-are-downvoted-answers-muted)) has a correct answer, I would like official documentation of this feature if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: @apaul34208 i would like official documentation, if it exists.

Comment: @apaul34208 does my edit create enough distinction?

Comment: Does the assumption in e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230657/274165 help you any?

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes actually, thank you!

Comment: [I found the real docs here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nathan Tuggy commented the link to the documentation.

[What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Thanks very much, Nathan!!

Answer (score 5):

This is because the post has been downvoted past a point where the system decides to hide it even more than just putting it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: i don't doubt you--but is there any official documentation on this feature?